# pandas to_csv on dataframe with a column that has dates below 1900

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I need to save to csv, but have date values in the series that are below 1900 (ie Mar 1 1899), which is preventing this from happening. I get `ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`. It seems a little absurd for a function like this to work only for dates above 1900s, so I think there must be something I am missing. What is the right way of getting a csv when you're working with a dataframe that has a column with dates before the 1900s?

Comment: Sorry is the dtype already `datetime`? won't it just export as is already?

Comment: I can parse that `Mar 1 1899` into a datetime and convert it to a string fine, can you post raw data and your code, also numpy and pandas versions

Comment: The dtype is already `datetime`, when I try to export it to csv, it gives me that error if and only if I have dates before the 1900s. The operative line in my code is `mergedSeries.to_csv(exportStore, index = False, header = False, date_format='%Y-%m', float_format='%.0f')`

Comment: That still works fine on my system I'm using pandas 0.17.1

Comment: pandas version 0.15.1, numpy version 1.8.1

Comment: could be a bug, can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: The update fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading pandas from 0.15.1 to 0.17.1 resolved this issue.